# chain multiple jquery commands

Tags: javascript, jquery, chaining

I've tried chaining and nesting, but possibly in the wrong style is there a more efficient way to execute these two lines?

```
$('#pub1, #pub1Tab').addClass('active');
$('#pub1').parent().addClass('active');
```

Comment: what is wrong with this code?

Comment: What exactly is it that you are trying to accomplish? I would assume that you mean "Add the class 'active' to both #pub1 and #pub1Tab".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use jquery [parent selector](http://api.jquery.com/parent-selector/)

```
$('#pub1, #pub1:parent, #pub1Tab').addClass('active');
```

Comment: Thanks thats what I needed: $('#pub1, :parent, #pub1Tab').addClass('active);

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#pub1').parent().andSelf().add('#pub1Tab').addClass('active');
```